# URL da origem na requisição REST do Angular

Tags: angular, http-request

Olá

Na requisição REST da aplicação Ionic com Angular está sendo adicionado automaticamente a URL da origem:

http://localhost:8100/127.0.0.1:5000/medicao?datainicial=2020-12-13&datafinal=2020-12-20

quando o correto seria:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/medicao?datainicial=2020-12-13&datafinal=2020-12-20

Não tenho interceptores http no código, não consigo identificar onde remover esse "http://localhost:8100" do início

A requisição no Angular:

```
public  apiURL = '127.0.0.1:5000'

getMedicoes(){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let param: any = {datainicial: '2020-12-13', datafinal: '2020-12-20'};
    console.log(this.http)
    return this.http.get<any>(this.apiURL+'/medicao',{headers: headers, params: param}).toPromise();
  }
```

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    Ng2GoogleChartsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
```

Agradeço qualquer tipo de ajuda, pois se eu tive o trabalho de escrever essa pergunta é pq eu já estou a no mínimo 4 horas tentando resolver esse problema, que para alguns deve ser bem básico.

Comment: Poderia colocar o trecho do código onde vc atribui o endereço da URL para a variável apiURL?

Comment: Se eu remover essa variável a requisição vai ficar http://localhost:8100/medicao?datainicial=2020-12-13&datafinal=2020-12-20

Answer (score 1):

No seu service, inclua o protocolo http na assinatura da variavel apiURL:

```js
public apiURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
```

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado